# Change wallpaper to slideshow in W7 with a script

Tags: windows, python-2.7, batch-file, command-line, registry

I'm looking for a way to change the wallpaper in W7 to a slideshow (2 images) with a Python script or a .bat.

I've searched the registry with regedit and was unable to find any slideshow-related setting/string, except for a path leading to both of the slideshow's images. Note that that was a a single string, changing it's path to the path of the current image every time the wallpaper image changed (on a 10s interval, set in the personalization menu under slideshow options), so even if I'd change it, it'd reset in the next 10s. Nothing else in the registry referencing it as far as I could find.

Any idea on how I could make this work?

Comment: it's probably a scheduled task of some sort, and the registry only ever has the current wallpaper's path in it.

Comment: Hm, I see. Any clue where/how I could alter the process?